# Promisify / async-await callback in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await

I have a c# function with a signature like:
`Foo(List<int> data, Action<string> endAction)`

I can't change Foo (it's an external library).

I'm very new to c#, I've mainly been doing JS development in recent years and I wonder if there's something similar to what is called 'promisify' in JS-land. That is, to make the function calling 'Foo' async and await for `Foo` to call the `endAction` callback.

Comment: No matter what you do `Foo` will run synchronously. If you're trying not to block a UI then you can offload the work using `Task.Run`. But that doesn't change the method to async, it will remain synchronous.

Comment: @JSteward, that is the answer. I suggest to expand a bit and write an actual answer.

Comment: You should provide an example in C#, JS or pseudo code how you would like to call the method.

Comment: The answer of Tom Deseyn below is the most what I was looking for. Basically Foo is doing some work in another Thread and calls 'endAction' when it finishes. I wanted to just `await Foo()` which returns when endAction is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make 'promisify' Foo as follows:

```
static Task<string> FooAsync(List<int> data)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
    Action action = () => Foo(data, result => tcs.SetResult(result));
    // If Foo isn't blocking, we can execute it in the ThreadPool:
    Task.Run(action);
    // If it is blocking for some time, it is better to create a dedicated thread
    // and avoid starving the ThreadPool. Instead of 'Task.Run' use:
    // Task.Factory.StartNew(action, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now you can call it:

```
string result = await FooAsync(myList);
```

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any built-in method similar to `promisify` in C#/.NET but you can use an instance of `TaskCompletionSource` to create a `Task` that can be completed when the callback is called.

```cs
TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
Foo(list, (string callbackData) => { tcs.SetResult(callbackData); });
string result = await tcs.Task;
```

Comment: The first and third lines are completely superfluous. Foo() still blocks.